# Использование obb файлов Unity

Tags: android, unity3d

Не нашёл никакой внятной документации по obb, поэтому решил обратиться сюда. В общем, apk не видит obb файл на андройд. Файл находится в нужной директории, сам apk запускается нормально.

На сколько я понимаю, ничего дополнительно с obb делать в коде не нужно и достаточно просто закинуть его в obb/*packagename*. Может ошибаюсь, поэтому очень жду вашей помощи.

Comment: Документацию читали? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html

Comment: Да, только проблему это все равно не решает. obb просто не подгружается.